Solana wallet provider
I'm working on a project and I need help  which Solana wallet connect provider to use on my platform. When a user clicks the connect button, it should display options for Solflare and Phantom wallets, allowing them to choose which one to connect.

Check out the wallet adapter guide for doing this https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md
By default, it will display the installed wallet extensions on the user's system.
